# how to make a page accessible from every other page in my app and able to unwind to where the segue comes from

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, segue, unwind-segue

I am trying to create an on-top structure where user can go to a general page G from any other pages with a special gesture and go back to the page where s/he comes from.

Is there a way to do this while not implementing a segue and an unwind segue from every other page to page G?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this without having a segue from each controller, but it depends on how your controller hierarchy is set up. If for instance, you have a navigation controller, and all your view controllers are pushed onto its stack, you can create one segue from the navigation controller to the one you want to go to from any of your other view controllers. You could also do this if your other controllers are embedded in a tab bar controller (the tab bar controller would present the common controller).